# SQL Debug not hitting break point in VS 2012 but does in VS2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have an MVC app that I have developed last year using VS 2010 and am able to hit sql trigger break points when opened with VS 2010 but the same app opened in VS 2012 I can't get any break point to work. I'm using SQL Server Object Explorer to set the break points but no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: I have opened a support ticket with Microsoft and will post solution once one has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has confirmed that setting a breakpoint does not work in Visual Studio 2012 as it does in 2010. In order to debug my trigger, I had to create a stored procedure that updated the table my trigger belongs to, then in VS 2012 I had to open SQL Server Object Explorer and navigate to the stored procedure, right click on it and select Debug Procedure. Stepping through the procedure took me to the trigger. The tech at Microsoft told me that they were working on making VS 2012 behave the same as 2010 but had no timeframe for completion. It's not that much of a work around, you just have to be aware of how to hit the trigger through a stored procedure.